# SQL - Getting Min from inner queries

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Considering we have the following table AAA:

```
V_ID int | S_ID int | FLAG bool | DATE date
1          100        1           14-10-2017
2          200        1           15-10-2017
3          100        1           19-10-2017
```

I want that for a same S_ID, only one row can have a FLAG=1 and that row must be the newest in date.

To get the S_IDs that have 2 rows with a FLAG=1 I use

```
SELECT S_ID FROM AAA WHERE FLAG=1 GROUP BY S_ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Which returns

```
S_ID
100
```

How do I manage do in 1 query:

1. Select S_ID that have more than one row with FLAG=1
2. Select the V_ID from the listed S_ID that have the oldest date

I tried the following:

```
SELECT V_ID, DATE FROM AAA WHERE S_ID IN (
SELECT S_ID FROM AAA WHERE FLAG=1 GROUP BY S_ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) AND FLAG=1;
```

Which gives me every pair of V_ID that belongs to a S_ID with 2 FLAGS=1.
How do I only get a list of the mins of each pair?

```
SELECT V_ID, MIN(DATE) FROM AAA WHERE S_ID IN (
SELECT S_ID FROM AAA WHERE FLAG=1 GROUP BY S_ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) AND FLAG=1 group by V_ID;

Doesn't change anyting..
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the `s_id`s that fail, then I'm thinking aggregation:

```
select s_id
from aaa
group by s_id
having sum(case when flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 1 or
       max(case when flag = 1 then date end) <> max(date)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm trying to get a list of v_id.
Multiple v_id can have the same s_id but not the other way around.

Trying to get the oldest v_id from an s_id that has multiple v_id with flag=1 (and this for all the s_id that are returned from my initial select)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
with aaa (v_id, s_id, flag, dt) as (
    select 3, 100, 1, to_date('14-10-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
    select 2, 200, 1, to_date('15-10-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
    select 1, 100, 1, to_date('19-10-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual
    )
select s_id, min(v_id) keep (dense_rank first order by dt) as v_id_for_1st_dt
     , min(dt)
from   aaa
group by s_id having count(*) > 1:
```

Gives:

```
      S_ID V_ID_FOR_1ST_DT MIN(DT)
---------- --------------- -----------
       100               3 14/10/2017
```

I have reversed the order of `v_id` values in the sample data to show that I really am picking the value associated with the earliest date. The `min()` is just a tiebreaker in case there are more than one for the same date.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following can do what you want

```
    Select v_id
    From aaa a1
    Join (
        Select s_id, min(date) maxdate
        From aaa
        Group by s_id
     ) t1 on a1.s_id = t1.s_id and
               a1.date = t1.maxdate
     Join (
       Select s_id
       From aaa
       Where flag = 1
       Group by s_id
       Having count(*) > 1
     ) t2 on a1.s_id = t2.s_id
```